# NGithub authentication and the github api in .net

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to use NGithub or any other kind of github api wrapper for .NET to interact with the GitHub website.
I am having a hard time authenticating myself.
I have a class `GitHubOAuthAuthorizer` and `NullAuthenticator` but `NullAuthenticator` is empty and `GitHubOAuthAuthorizer` has 2 methods that I don't understand how to use. One just builds a url(returns a string) don't know how I am supposed to use that and the other one wants me to suppy it with something called a user secret and a user code, I don't know what those are I just know the username and the password.
I also tried GithubSharp which doesn't build.
Is there any example of actually logging in to github and adding a issue to the issue tracker from .NET?
This is what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/tekstop/Git2BitIssues

Looked here and found the final solution